# Displaying a pair that have same value in another table

Tags: sql

I'm trying to make a query that pair a worker that work  on the same place. The relational model I'm asking looks like this:

Employee(**EmNum**, name)
Work(**FiNum*, EmNum***)
Field(**FiNum**, Title)
(bold indicates primary key)

right now my code looks like

```
SELECT work.finum, e1.name,e1.emnum,e2.name,e2.emnum
FROM employee e1
INNER JOIN employee e2
  on e1.EmNum = e2.EmNum 
INNER JOIN work
  on e1.emnum = work.emnum
```

This gives me result like

```
| finum | name | emnum | name_1 | emnum_1 | 
|   1   |   a  |   1   |    a   |    1    | 
|   1   |   b  |   2   |    b   |    2    | 
|   2   |   c  |   3   |    c   |    3    | 
|   3   |   d  |   4   |    d   |    4    | 
|   3   |   e  |   5   |    e   |    5    |
```

while I want the result to be like

```
| finum | name | emnum | name_1 | emnum_1 | 
|   1   |   a  |   1   |    b   |    2    | 
|   1   |   b  |   2   |    a   |    1    | 
|   3   |   d  |   4   |    e   |    4    | 
|   3   |   e  |   5   |    d   |    5    |
```

I'm quite new at sql so I can't really think of a way to do this. Any help or input would be helpful.

Thanks

Comment: you should only choose one rdbms not 3.

Comment: and the last 2 row `emnum_1` of your expected result should be 5 and 4 respectively. am i right ?

Comment: Oh yeah it should be 5 and 4. sorry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is slightly unclear, but my guess is that you're trying to find employees that worked on the same place = same finum in work, but different row. That you can do this way:

```
SELECT w1.finum, e1.name,e1.emnum, e2.name,e2.emnum
from work w1
join work w2 on w1.finum = w2.finum and w1.emnum != w2.emnum
join employee e1 on e1.emnum = w1.emnum
join employee e2 on e2.emnum = w2.emnum
```

If you don't want to repeat the records (1 <-> 2 + 2 <-> 1 change the != in the join to > or <)

Comment: Oh man thanks a lot. I just started using sql so I guess my logic isn't there yet. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

> I'm trying to make a query that pair a worker that work on the same place.

Presumably the "places" are represented by the `Field` table.  If you want to pair up employees on that basis then you should be performing a join conditioned on field numbers being the same, as opposed to one conditioned on employee numbers being the same.

It looks like your main join wants to be a self-join of `Work` to `Work` of records with matching `FiNum`.  To get the employee names in the result then you will need also to join `Employee` twice.  To avoid employees being paired with themselves, you will want to filter those cases out via a `WHERE` clause.